# Could not make private broadcast method work

Tags: java, mysql, sockets, server, tcp

I modified an open-source project on github for a school project to fit my needs 
it had a `broadcast()` method to send messages and it was called in the `run()` method in a while loop but the problem is that `broadcast()` sends a message to all users in a `userList<>`i wanted to add the ability to send a private message to one of the users by writing `@username`.

Here is the code for broadcast method:

```
private synchronized void broadcast(String msg) {
    for (int i = 0; i < clientList.size(); i++) {
        clientList.get(i).write(msg);
    }
    System.out.println("Log: Message broadcast --> " + msg);
}
```

and here is the run() method

```
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Log: Got input/output streams for connected client.");

    /** Get the first message from the client, attempt communication */
    String clientMsg = null;
    boolean accepted = false;

    /** Allow client to create an account, login, or quit */
    do {
        clientMsg = client.read();
        if (clientMsg.equals("QUIT")) {
            System.out.println("Log: Client disconnected without signing in.");
            client.disconnect();
            return;
        }
        else if (clientMsg.startsWith("NEWUSER: ")) {
            createUser(clientMsg);
        }
        else if (clientMsg.startsWith("LOGIN: ")) {
            accepted = authenticate(clientMsg);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Log: Unexpected client message -> " + clientMsg);
            client.disconnect();
            return;
        }
    } while(!accepted);

    /** Run main chat loop. Will read from the client, and broadcast each read
     *  until the client disconnects. */
    while (true) {
                int i=0;
                String username= clientList.get(i).getUsername();
        String line = client.read();
        if (line == null) break;
                    else if(line.startsWith("@"+username)){
                     broadcastp(line,username);
                    }
        else {

                        broadcast(line);

                    }
i++;
    }

    /** The only way for the client to exit the above loop is to disconnect.
     *  Therefore, call the handler's exit routine */
    exit();
}
```

Here is the `broadcastp()` method that i tried to implement this feature with, but it doesn't work. It compiles and runs perfectly though just without the private chat feature.

```
  private synchronized void broadcastp(String msg,String username) {
             for (int i = 0; i < clientList.size(); i++) {
        username = clientList.get(i).getUsername();
        if(msg.startsWith("@"+username))
        {clientList.get(i).write(msg);}
        else {
        continue;
        }}
    System.out.println("Log: Message broadcast --> " + msg);}
```

Comment: So what is the problem ?

Comment: it's a chat app i made broadcastp so it enables clients to send private messages to each other given that the regular broadcast sends it to all clients in the arraylist

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the full picture of how your program works, but you say the program runs perfectly, but does not do the private messaging part.

If I look at your code, in the `while` loop you always take the first username from the `clientList` (`i = 0`) and only call `broadcastp` if the line starts with that name.

First of all.. is `broadcastp` ever invoked? In `broadcastp` you have another loop, but that will always match on `i == 0` given the way you invoke it (with the line and username from the `while` loop).

The problem seems to be be there. So something like this within the while loop might work for you (remove the `i` variable, and no need for `broadcastp`):

```
boolean isPrivate = false;
String line = client.read();

for (User user : clientList) {
    if (line.startsWith("@" + user.getUsername())) {
        user.write(line);
        isPrivate = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!isPrivate) {
    broadcast(line);
}
```

Comment: it's a chat app i made broadcastp so it enables clients to send private messages to each other given that the regular broadcast sends it to all clients in the arraylist
i have a client file a dbmanager file and a session file but for the messages only the server is concerned as you can see

Comment: i added i++ in the first while loop still doesn't work and for the second loop i am iterating through the clients arraylist doesn't work i figured i would add a continue didn't help

Comment: That won't work, because in the same loop - at the top - you reset it again. Instead you should iterate the clientList with its own loop inside the while loop and check for a username match at the start of the line, in which case you do `broadcastp`, and otherwise you do just `broadcast`.

Comment: so you are suggesting that i use an iterator in the while loop and keeping 
    broadcastp    as it is or using an iterator in both?

Comment: See my additional edit (presuming there are `User` objects in `clientList`).

Comment: now it tells me that the exit(); statement is unreachable

Comment: and it didn't work even after removing the exit() statement

Comment: This is a different issue than your question. The `exit()` statement is outside of your while loop - which is endless - so it can never be reached, once inside. You need to figure out a different mechanism for breaking the loop.

Comment: Well, you should check then if your lines indeed start with '@username'

Comment: PS You don't have to upvote me if my answer helped you, but looking at your prior questions, you don't do that in general. Just wanted to say: Please reconsider. It is how stackoverflow works, and an instrument to keep people being inclined to spend their time to help others.